# Filter results based on foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys

Suppose I have 4 tables: `collections`, `venues`, `locations` and `cities`.

A `Collection` belongs to many `Venues` and a `Venue` belong to many `Collections`.

There is a one to one relationship between a `Venue` and a `Location` (through `id` field)

A `Location` Belongs to a `City` and a `City` has many `Locations`.

What I want to achieve is this scenario:

if  I have  a record's `id` on `cities` table, I want to get all `collections` and `venues` in each `collection` associated with `id` on `cities` table.

How would I achieve this?
I tried to be as specific as possible,but if something is still vague mention.
I'm using Laravel. so if you provide in Eloquent I would be grateful but SQL query is ok too.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize the keys of the table you gave reference

```
SELECT co.anycolumn, v.anycolumn FROM collections co, venues v, cities ci, locations lo WHERE co.id = v.refid AND ci.refid = lo.refid AND lo = 'WantedLoc';
```

Simple Logic:
`SELECT` --> desired column values
`FROM` --> referenced the tables
`WHERE` --> condition

Answer (score 0):

You could write a standard SQL query like below however I believe more information regarding your table structure is required to give a full answer to your question, especially the many to many join between collections and venues.

```
Select ci.Id, ci.Header, co.Header,* from Cities ci
inner join Locations l on l.id = ci.LocationId 
inner join Venues v on v.id = l.VenueId 
inner join Collections co on co.Id = v.CollectionId -- this is going to be a problem
```

> A Collection belongs to many Venues and a Venue belong to many Collections

Many to many is not a good database relationship design pattern I would recommend a link table to break these into many to one connections, this would also simplify the query required if possible.

^Edit Laravel/Eloquent might handle this better but in my experience just because you can do something doesn't mean you should, see [SQL JOIN many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774373/sql-join-many-to-many) for a nice way to handle many to many in a sql query or [Many to Many join Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157825/many-to-many-join-laravel-eloquent) might help.